# where can I download .NET 4.5 redistributable (official MS link)

Tags: .net-4.5

Strangely I cannot find anywhere on MS site 4.5 redistributable (offline) version. There are [links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx) for both 4.5.1 and 4.5.2, but not for 4.5.

Anyone knows why is this the case?

Comment: It is pretty explicit in the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Why is the sky blue?  Might have something to do [with this](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/2749655).

Comment: One mans explicit is another mans clear as mud. The MSDN page says that it's part of the SDK, but when you check the SDK page, it says that it needs to be downloaded separately and provides the link I posted.

Comment: @HansPassant I have placed a link to the explicit page you linked. I do not see anything explicit there, except that the link is explicitly not there - and I wondered why. However, if you go to web download link, in the details you can see a note that points to your second link. That is what concerned me, and so the question. Does it mean that we should not distribute 4.5 version at all (as a prerequisite for our applications)? Still in the mud...

Comment: If anyone lands here trying to install DWG TrueView 2015 when it insists that .NET 4.5 is not installed (when you have .NET 4.5.1 or higher installed), [this is a known issue in their installer](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Error-NET-4-5-is-not-installed-when-attempting-to-install-Autodesk-2016-products-on-Windows-10.html). It looks like Autodesk wasn't prepared for .NET 4.5.X and they hardcoded something. I fixed it by updating to DWG TrueView 2018...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: Nevermind, this file size is too small to be the redistributable:

Version: 4.5
File Name: dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe
Date Published: 10/9/2012
File Size: 982 KB
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) table it *appears* that there is no "offline installer".
However, if you follow the link to the SDK [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363) there is a link to download it.

[Download .NET 4.5 Redistrubuteable](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=225702)

[image]

Comment: No, 982 KB is a bit small :)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Now the question is does that link contain a version which does not suffer from signing issue that is addressed in the first link you posted (under details sections), and about which Hans Passant talks about in question comments.

Comment: That would be a different question.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott ...to which you know answer or not?

Comment: I don't know. It's a new question, so please ask in a new question. Thanks.

Comment: @Goran did you post that question about the signed binaries? Did it get deleted? I can't find it in your question history.